# stellarium software: selective artificial satellite display

Tags: artificial-satellite, stellarium

The Stellarium satellite plugin by default shows all the artificial satellites' orbits around Earth. I’d like to be able to view only certain satellites so that the view is not cluttered with every satellite in existence. Is there a means to create a custom satellite list, or view only relevant satellites?

Comment: As it might be relevant, which exact satellites do you want to show/hide?

Comment: To begin with, I’d like to keep meteosat-8 in view, then ideally add others satellites as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Satellites are provided by a plug-in (that is enabled by default)

Configuration (the spanner-and-star button) -> plug-ins -> Satellites -> configure.  You can configure which satellites to display from here.

It might be worth noting that meteosat-8, a geostationary satellite has a magnitude of about 19, and so is not a naked eye object, and is in fact beyond the capabilities of most amateur equipment.

Comment: Where does +19 magnitude come from, the plug-in? Answer(s) to [How bright are geostationary satellites due to reflected sunlight?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38667/7982) have more information

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t seem possible to have a general view of selected satellites, however the bookmark plugin seems the best workaround to keep a custom list without having to search satellite plugin configuration panel each time.